# Where art they, Django-Paypal signals

Tags: django, django-paypal

Im using Django and django-paypal to try and setup a payment system.

Using the [developer IPN simulator](https://developer.paypal.com/developer/ipnSimulator/) I can send posts to my server to test with.

```
[13/Sep/2015 18:54:08] "POST /paypal/ HTTP/1.1" 200 4
```

There is the post coming through from the simulator, no problems.

Now I want to get the signal fireing. I put the following in one of my aps models.py as in the [documentation](https://django-paypal.readthedocs.org/en/stable/standard/ipn.html?highlight=signals):

```
from paypal.standard.models import ST_PP_COMPLETED
from paypal.standard.ipn.signals import valid_ipn_received

def show_me_the_money(sender, **kwargs):
    print "Hello"
    ipn_obj = sender
    if ipn_obj.payment_status == ST_PP_COMPLETED:
        # Undertake some action depending upon `ipn_obj`.
        if ipn_obj.custom == "Upgrade all users!":
            Users.objects.update(paid=True)
    else:
        #...

valid_ipn_received.connect(show_me_the_money)
```

But I never get any repsonse from the signal.

I have no idea why? And I don't know how else to test this

Answer (score -1):

I'm not familiar with this library, but are you defining your `receiver` and `sender`?

For example, on a `post_save` signal, I would structure it like this:

```
post_save.connect(receiver=my_function, sender=myModel)
```

It looks like `show_me_the_money` the money is the receiver of the signal, but it's not clear here what is firing the signal. Perhaps it should be:

```
post_save.connect(receiver=my_function, sender=ST_PP_COMPLETED)
```

Comment: The signal is triggered by Paypal `Webhook` instead of manually